# What does it mean by useState are asycnhronous in react

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I found some old post that a guy having problem with his code in React and alot answer said that it was caused by because useState is asycnhronous. I was curious what it mean by asycnhronous and I found this article

> useState is an asynchronous hook and it doesn't change the state
> immediately, it has to wait for the component to re-render. useRef is
> a synchronous hook that updates the state immediately and persists its
> value through the component's lifecycle, but it doesn't trigger a
> re-render

But i still don't understand what it means and why is such a problem. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: _"some old post"_ - this is the internet, bring links. It's a problem only if you expect it **not** to be asynchronous, if you expect React to magically rebind the value you closed over. And if you want to see what happens when you do so, just read those other questions where people ask why `useState` "doesn't work": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/54069253?lq=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this is one of the myth to call `useState` asynchronous.

IMHO, if you open the source code of react, I'm speaking to react 16.x and below (because i didn't read after 16), `useState` isn't asynchronous.

So why are we saying `useState` behaves as asynchronous code? We need some coding example.

```
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1)
  const onClick = () => {
    setValue(2)
    console.log(value)
  }
  
  return <input value={value} />
}
```

In the above typical setup of `useState`, when you call `setValue(2)`, `value` wouldn't become `2` right away. This is apparent if you put a `console.log` after that. Then why the `input` does show `2` instead of `1`, you might ask?

That's because React made a second render to `App`, you can think of `App` has been called one more time after `setValue`. For this reason, people call `useState` async.

But then why I'm not calling `useState` async? well, this is a bit long story. The short story is that `useState` is implemented inside React using plain non-async codes, therefore you can't say a code async just because it has been called twice or it has been deferred to call. Async means a bit differently in Javascript. This is another topic which I won't get into here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to speak for the React team as to why state changes are asynchronous, but here's some random dude's explanation. I'll be referring to the JavaScript event loop, which is basically a program that runs many times per second. Each time it runs, it processes a series of tasks synchronously. Asynchronous code is executed across several event loops. This is a very basic and oversimplified explanation - you should go read more about the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

So your initial state declaration happens in your initial render - the first time the function is called. This initial render happens synchronously - meaning the function is executed top to bottom in a single event loop. It's worth pointing out that React components cannot be `async`:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState("bar");

  return <div>The value of foo is "{bar}"</div>;
}
```

After your initial render, the state only changes when something happens: user clicks a button, the screen resizes, a timer interval fires, etc. Whenever an "event" happens, there can be a lot of processing going on in the JavaScript event loop.

Let's look at a button click, the event propagates all the way down and back up the entire DOM tree which contains the button. The browser is also rendering different states of the button, causing the browser to repaint. You also have developer code which is running in the button click handler which might be doing some heavy lifting like iterating over an array. This all happens within a single event loop. The point of this explanation is to convey that "a lot is going on". Eventually, the state will get updated with `setFoo(...)`.

At this point, React now has to figure out which component changed, calculate and rerender your application in a [virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html), perform a diff with the actual DOM, and then apply any changes to the actual DOM. Only at this point does the browser finally paint the result to the screen. This whole operation can be very taxing on a CPU.

If react were to handle state changes synchronously, all of this virtual DOM diffing and calculating would happen in the same event loop as the initial button click. It is very likely that most apps would cause the browser to sporadically freeze and jitter because the CPU is doing so much work at one time.

There are also some other things to consider. Suppose the window resizes and a bunch of different components perform some calculations and update their state. You don't want react to synchronously rerender every time a component changes its state. You want react to kind of wait and collect a whole bunch of state changes and process them at the same time. Browsers also provide mechanisms like [requestAnimationFrame](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/) to help web-based applications asynchronously render in such a way that works best for the user and their system/browser resources.

There are many other things to consider, but this post is getting long. Hope this helps.